# How to take info from sub-object in request before validating in Django?

Tags: json, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I'm writing an api in Django for which I use the [django-rest-framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/). I've got a simple model as follows:

```
class PeopleCounter(models.Model):
    version = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True)
    sensor = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    count = models.IntegerField()
```

And I've got a serializer as follows:

```
class PeopleCounterSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = PeopleCounter
        fields = [
            'version',
            'timestamp',
            'sensor',
            'count',
        ]
```

When I post the following data to this endpoint it works great:

```
{
    "version": "v1",
    "timestamp": "2019-04-01T20:00:00.312",
    "sensor": "sensorA",
    "count": 4
}
```

but unfortunately I need to adjust the endpoint for the data to arrive as follows:

```
{
    "version": "v1",
    "timestamp": "2019-04-01T20:00:00.312",
    "data": {
        "sensor": "sensorA",
        "count": 4
    }
}
```

I thought I needed to add a create method to the serializer class. So I tried that, but when I post the json with the `"data"` object I get a message that the sensor field and the count field are required.

Where can I normalize this data so that I can insert it in the database correctly?

Also, what if I want to serve the data through the same endpoint like this as well, where would I be able to define that?

Answer (score 2):

One of possible ways is implement it on view level. If you are using CBV override `get_serializer` something like this:

```
def get_serializer(self, *args, **kwargs):
    request_body = kwargs.get("data")  # obtain request body
    data = request_body.get("data")  # get data
    request_body.update(data)  # add data as request_body attributes
    kwargs["data"] = request_body  # override received request_body with updated one

    serializer_class = self.get_serializer_class()
    kwargs['context'] = self.get_serializer_context()
    return serializer_class(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Since I'm a Django beginner, it took me some time to understand that CBV meant "Class Based View" and where I had to put this in, but I managed and now it works great! One more thing; do you know how I can serve this over the api using the same structure again as well (so with `sensor` and `count` in `"data"`)?

Comment: @kramer65 if you need to extend this logic to multiple views you can try to do it in custom parser: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/#custom-parsers

Comment: @kramer65 add custom middleware is another option I beleive https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/middleware/